# from recursion to if else statments

Tags: java, recursion

how do I transform this into a if else statement? im stuck in one part with the comment below. I would like to separate knapsack() into if statements.

```
static int max_val(int a, int b){
    
    return(a>b)? a: b; //set value for a = 1 and b = 0
  }

static int knapsack(int max_bag_limit, int[] weight, int[] value, int size){
    
    if (size ==0 || max_bag_limit == 0){ //base case
      return 0;
    }
    
    if(weight[size - 1] > max_bag_limit){
      return knapsack(max_bag_limit, weight, value, size-1);
    }
    else{
      return max_val(value[size-1]
                + knapsack(max_bag_limit - weight[size - 1],weight,value, size -1), //im stuck at this line
                    knapsack(max_bag_limit, weight, value, size -1) );     
    }
    
  }
```

i tried to do it this way because i need to put it in a Jbutton.

```
    else if(counter == 6){ //max_val compare knapsack A and Knapsack B
        printCode(1);
        if(knapsackA>knapsackB){
            total = knapsackA;
        }
        else total = knapsackB;
    }
    else count = 1; // to avoid 0;
    }
```

Comment: You already have if...else statements. Which part do you think also needs to be if...else statements and why?

Comment: i would like to break down the code into if statements because i have to apply it to a jButton for a simulation

Comment: What will this JButton do when you click on it?

Comment: Hint: recursion is about REPEATING things. If/else alone doesnt give you that. Meaning: if you want to turn your recursive method into something else, you will need some sort of explicit LOOPING instead. So it is probably not about if/else but *while*

Comment: simulate the knapsack() step by step.

Comment: @Ella So when the user clicks the button it will perform one step of the knapsack solution and draw something to represent that step? Is this what you are saying?

Comment: yes, im sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To allow more control over the algorithm, you need to break out one step to perform. This means that you need to think about what to do for a single step and what state you need to store so that you can perform the next step. A direct reimplementation of recursion can use an explicit `Stack` instead of relying on the call stack in the JRE.